# How is JIF quartile determined in JCR?

Tags: bibliometrics

According to JCR 2020, a given journal has a *Journal Impact Factor* (JIF) percentile of 75.18. As a result, I would expect a JIF quartile of Q1, since the percentile is > 75, but the reported JIF quartile is Q2. Is this due to some rounding error, or am I missing something?

Comment: This isn't my expertise, but is it just a matter of one computation being out of sync (in time) with another. Impact Factors change, I assume.